# Java SWT ScrolledForm Background Color

Tags: java, background, swt

I am having an issue with a `ScrolledForm`. I am trying to change the background and foreground colour for a `Label` defined in the body of the `ScrolledForm`, however it doesn't seem to be working.

In my code snippet, I would like `lblWhat` to have a black background and white foreground.

Here is my code snippet:

```
ScrolledForm scrldfrmNewScrolledform = formToolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);

scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setLayoutData(gd);

scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 16, SWT.NORMAL));
scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
scrldfrmNewScrolledform.getBody().setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(EPRForm.class, "/icons/AFCCEPR.png"));
scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setBounds(10, 10, 430, 280);
formToolkit.paintBordersFor(scrldfrmNewScrolledform);
scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setText("ePR (electronic Purchase Request)");

Label lblName = new Label(scrldfrmNewScrolledform.getBody(), SWT.NONE);
lblName.setBounds(10, 21, 55, 15);
formToolkit.adapt(lblName, true, true);
lblName.setText("Name:");

text = new Text(scrldfrmNewScrolledform.getBody(), SWT.BORDER);
text.setBounds(71, 15, 269, 21);
formToolkit.adapt(text, true, true);

Label lblWhat = new Label(scrldfrmNewScrolledform.getBody(), SWT.None);
lblWhat.setBounds(10, 35, 100, 15);
lblWhat.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
lblWhat.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
formToolkit.adapt(lblWhat, true, true);
lblWhat.setText("What do you want?");

Label lblItem = new Label(scrldfrmNewScrolledform.getBody(), SWT.None);
lblItem.setBounds(10, 55, 100, 15);
formToolkit.adapt(lblItem, true, true);
lblItem.setText("Items to be Ordered*");

txtItems = new Text(scrldfrmNewScrolledform.getBody(), SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.CANCEL);
txtItems.setBounds(10, 60, 338, 84);
formToolkit.adapt(txtItems, true, true);
```

Comment: As an aside you should look at using [Layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). `setBounds` will cause problems if you change the font or try to make tne window resizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `FormToolkit`. The `FormToolkit.adapt` method forces the control colors to the colors set for the form (normally white background and black text).

For a single control you could try calling `setBackground` and `setForeground` after the `adapt` call.

You can set the colors for the entire form with

```
FormColors colors = toolkit.getColors();

colors.setBackground(...);
colors.setForeground(...);
```